# Jsoup - read one by one

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm starting to use Jsoup recently. I need list some elements in a HTML source. For example:

```
 <table class="list">
    <tr>
        <td class="year" colspan="5">2012</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="code">COMP0348</td>
        <td class="name">Software Engineering</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="code">COMP0734</td>
        <td class="name">System Information</td>
    </tr>
    <td class="year" colspan="5">2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="code">COMP999</td>
        <td class="name">Windows</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**This is what I want:**

```
2012 
Comp0348 Software Engineering
COMP0734 System Information
2013
COMP999 Windows
```

But in my code, it's not list one by one, it's list one string containing first all "year", and after in another line containing all "code" and after in another line all "name". 
Like:

```
2012 
Comp0348 COMP0734 COMP999
Software Engineering System Information Windows
```

How can I do this?

Comment: show your jsoup related code

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only select the tags by criteria, but not the structure.

But see here:

```
Document doc = ...

Element table = doc.select("table.list").first(); // select the table


for( Element element : table.select("tr") ) // select all 'tr' of the table
{
    final Elements td = element.select("td.year"); // select the 'td' with 'year' class

    if( !td.isEmpty() ) // if it's the one with the 'year' class
    {
        final String year = td.first().text(); // get year

        System.out.println(year);
    }
    else // if it's another 'tr' tag containing the 'code' and 'name' element
    {
        final String code = element.select("td.code").first().text(); // get code
        final String name = element.select("td.name").first().text(); // get name

        System.out.println(code + " " + name);
    }
}
```

**Output (using your html):**

```
2012
COMP0348 Software Engineering
COMP0734 System Information
2013
COMP999 Windows
```